# CSRF Token is not working in my react app

Tags: node.js, csrf

Do csrf tokens work when the client and server are hosted on 2 different servers? I am currently in development and my client is hosted in localhost:3000 and server in localhost:8000.

If yes, is it possible to get csrf to work in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Disable CSRF in your case. You are not logged in via session, so you don't need it.